# Combining C and python with Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    double x;
    double pi;
    pi = M_PI;
    double increment;
    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen ("FILE","w");
    x = 0;
    increment = 4* pi / 500;

    for (i = 0; i<=500; i++)
    {
        x = i * increment;
        printf("i: %d, tan(x): %f\n", i, tanf(x));
        fprintf (fp, "%d, %f\n",i, tanf(x));

    }
    fclose (fp);
    exit(0);
}
```

And the following Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


f = open("FILE", "r")
lines=f.readlines()
first =[]
second=[]
for x in lines:
    first.append(int(x.split(', ')[0]))
    second.append(float(x.split(', ')[1]))
f.close()

plt.plot(first, second)
plt.show()

os.remove("FILE")
```

The C codes generates data that is saved in a text file. The python code reads that textfile and makes a plot. After making a plot, python deletes the datafile.

I need to make a bash file that executes both pieces of code, like a sort of glue. I've read tutorials about bash, but it's still unclear to me how to compile and execute C and run python.

Question: How do I make a bash file that runs both pieces of code in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty trivial once your C program is compiled into an executable (binary). Let's assume your C program generates executable `table`, and your python script is called `plot.py`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./table && python plot.py
```

This will just run these two programs in sequence. The `&&` means that the second program will only run if the first one completes successfully (exit code == 0).

PS: In case you still need to compile your C-code, use `gcc filename.c -lm`. The `-lm` will make sure the math library where `tanf` is defined is linked.

Comment: Thanks! I called my C function table.c and my python3 program plot.py. When the C program is compiled I get a new file with the name 'table'. Is that the executable? So my bash file has to include 

"" table.out && python3 plot.py ""

Comment: @Terr070, a bash script is basically the same as you typing commands one after another.

Note the shell (bash) will not execute a file in the current directory unless you explicitly tell it to. This is because the current directory isn't in your $PATH. "./table.out" is sufficient. Also, you will need to `chmod +x {scriptname}` to "set the executable flag". This tells the shell that you intend for the file to be executed as a script.